# How can I simply iterate through JSON that has a multileveled encapsulation with (Google) Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I want to retrieve the current prices of specific crypto currencies and update some fields in my google sheet.

Here a short codesnippet:

```
  var api_url = "API-URL";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url);
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

@When executing the URL in a Browser, I get this for dataAll:

[dataAll content on Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls8uC.png)

@When executing it in the Google Script Editor, the Google Runtime Environment has this

[dataAll content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUzil.png)

@Here the rawdata response of the api-url call in JSON-Format with just 1 crypto entry in the data:

```
{"status":{"timestamp":"2021-04-01T21:11:59.721Z","error_code":0,"error_message":null,"elapsed":13,"credit_count":1,"notice":null,"total_count":4567},"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","slug":"bitcoin","num_market_pairs":9477,"date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z","tags":["mineable","pow","sha-256","store-of-value","state-channels","coinbase-ventures-portfolio","three-arrows-capital-portfolio","polychain-capital-portfolio","binance-labs-portfolio","arrington-xrp-capital","blockchain-capital-portfolio","boostvc-portfolio","cms-holdings-portfolio","dcg-portfolio","dragonfly-capital-portfolio","electric-capital-portfolio","fabric-ventures-portfolio","framework-ventures","galaxy-digital-portfolio","huobi-capital","alameda-research-portfolio","a16z-portfolio","1confirmation-portfolio","winklevoss-capital","usv-portfolio","placeholder-ventures-portfolio","pantera-capital-portfolio","multicoin-capital-portfolio","paradigm-xzy-screener"],"max_supply":21000000,"circulating_supply":18670918,"total_supply":18670918,"platform":null,"cmc_rank":1,"last_updated":"2021-04-01T21:11:03.000Z","quote":{"CHF":{"price":55752.47839320199,"volume_24h":59267607529.77155,"percent_change_1h":0.02671823,"percent_change_24h":0.05924755,"percent_change_7d":11.47320017,"percent_change_30d":24.2882489,"percent_change_60d":81.38470939,"percent_change_90d":102.84247336,"market_cap":1040949952376.2463,"last_updated":"2021-04-01T21:11:15.000Z"}}}]}
```

For better readability I just pasted it into e.g. Notepad++ and went for Menu > JSON Viewer > Format JSON.

I know it's really basic, but how the heck can I now iterate through this encapsulated Object and dig to the appropriate level so I can read the price? I only want to pick a specific cryptocurrency, e.g. Ethereum which has id: 1027 and take its price for further purposes.

I want to be able to pick just the entries that fit to my portfolio (e.g. distinguish with id:) and take its price for a specific cell update in my google sheet.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Best regards
Doniberi

Answer (score 1):

```
if you want to get data by name just filter it

  const api_url = 'API-URL';
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url);
  const dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  const etherealData = dataAll.data.find(item => item.name === 'Ethereum');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function postDataToSheet() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const selected=['Symbol1','Symbol2']
  const api_url = "API-URL";
  let r= UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url);
  let rjson = r.getContentText();
  let robj = JSON.parse(rjson);
  let vs=[];
  const ts=robj.status.timestamp;
  const tc=robj.status.total_count;
  vs.push(['TimeStamp',ts,'']);
  vs.push('Total Count',tc,'');
  vs.push(['Id','Symbol','Price']);

  //***************************************************
  //use this one to put them all on a sheet
  robj.data.forEach((item,i)=>{
    vs.push([item.id,item.symbol,item.quote.CHF.price])
  });
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);

  //***************************************************
  //use this one to put only the selected on a sheet
  robj.data.forEach((item,i)=>{
    if(~selected.index(item.symbol)) {
      vs.push([item.id,item.symbol,item.quote.CHF.price])
    }
  });
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need current price I'm pretty sure you can remove all the code and use something like `=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")` to fetch crypto prices.

No complex parsing, no authentication, no limitations.